# EDT violation detected when scaling image in Codename one

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to develop an app that will show arbitrary image that is scaled to fit screen size. However, scaling the image on EDT will show down the UI considerably, so I decided to scale the image in a background thread, using the following code.

```
    final Runnable updateUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //Update the UI here
        }
    };
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Image i = Resources.getGlobalResources().getImage("apple-icon.png");
            i.scaled(50, 40);
            //Display.getInstance().callSerially(updateUI);
            //This line of code is not related to the EDT error
        }
    };
    new Thread(r).start();
```

But despite the image is not on GUI (yet), the simulator shows the following error in console (repeated hundreds times, sometimes incomplete stack is printed):

```
EDT violation detected!
com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$EDTViolation: EDT Violation Stack!
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.checkEDT(JavaSEPort.java:545)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.getImageWidth(JavaSEPort.java:3945)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.getWidth(Image.java:689)
    at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getWidth(EncodedImage.java:511)
    at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.scaledEncoded(EncodedImage.java:600)
    at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.scaled(EncodedImage.java:653)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication$1.run(MyApplication.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I wonder if this is expected behavior or a bug in my code, and how to get rid of this error? Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should generally work despite the warning, in fact our code does exactly that and produces an EDT warning.

Detecting EDT violations is inaccurate as some EDT violations can occur without reaching the implementation layer. That is why we choose to be over eager and prefer to have a "false positive" than missing the mark entirely.

Notice that while scaling should work off the EDT some other image manipulations might not. E.g. drawing on an image in the background could fail very badly on iOS.

Comment: I comment this old question to ask a clarification: is there any list of operations that work (or don't work) off the EDT? About the "EDT Violations", the [manual section](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/edt.html#_debugging_edt_violations) is generic and don't say anything about image manipulations.

Comment: There is no official support for images off the EDT which is why it isn't mentioned. Methods that work off the EDT or are expected to be threadsafe are explicitly mentioned in the JavaDoc. Everything else should be on the EDT always